# Sending with data Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

i just created ajax script which sends data to php file but, something is wrong coz when i send javascript var variable "browserLang ", i get an error that not defined. Here is my javascript:

```
function SetLang() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var browserLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","style/wps-light/datalife3.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("BrowserLang=" + encodeURIComponent(userLang));
}
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you define `browserLang` but send `userLang`

```
function SetLang() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var browserLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","style/wps-light/datalife3.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("BrowserLang=" + encodeURIComponent(browserLang));
}
```